# Under extrusion on one side, but only while printing support material

Tags: underextrusion, print-failure, support-material, flashforge, flashprint

Trying to print a bracket for pliers, however the support material on the left side always fails by under extruding. The model is left-right symetrical, so the support is the same for both sides. However, only the right side prints flawlessly, while the left side barely extrudes any material at all. So far, I have tried increasing the extrusion multiplier to 125% (from default 109% - actually resulted in less support printed on left side), increasing the density of the support material and reducing retraction distance while increasing the retraction speed. I cannot get the left side support to print properly. The actual model prints without any issue, only the support material is failing to print.
I am using a Flashforge Creator Pro and Flashprint slicer software.

I allowed one of the prints to finish, pausing numerous times to add/adjust some tape to the almost non-existent left support structure to help hold it together. Once it reached the top part of the model where it printed the overhanging portion, it printed near-perfect, with some minor under-extrusion along the way (as seen in the first image)

[image]

I can't remember the exact settings used for each attempt, but I can recall (mostly) the settings I adjusted
[image: Default extrusion multiplier (109%)]
^^ Default extrusion multiplier (109%)

[image: 116% extrusion multiplier]
^^ 116% extrusion multiplier (little perceivable difference to default)

[image: 125% extrusion multiplier]
^^ 125% extrusion multiplier (less extruded support material)

[image: Left side support failing to print, right side perfect]
^^ Left side support failing to print, right side perfect

---

*I have noticed there is a delay between when the extruder "starts" extruding and filament actually coming out. The print head moves during this time as though expecting filament to be extruding resulting in the first few cm being under-extruded, or not extruded at all.*

Comment: Almost surely the slicer is skipping retraction in support, thereby oozing out all the material that's needed somewhere else. Classic bad Cura behavior. Wouldn't be surprised if Flashprint does it too.

Comment: Thanks. I have since noticed there is a delay between when the extruder "starts" extruding and filament actually coming out. The print head still moves during this time resulting in the first few cm being under extruded, or not extruded at all

Comment: Another supposed cause for this type of problem is moisture in your filament. My guess at the mechanism would be water absorbing lots of the energy intended to heat and melt the filament after unretract due to its high specific heat and phase transition energy, only allowing the filament to start flowing once it's all boiled off.